# Delphi infinite loop

Tags: delphi, random

The program should read a list and extract a random line from the list. The problem I have is when i have more extractions that the list lines. The program crashes. How can I make it repeat lines in the random sequence and don't crash?

Here is a link for the files:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TVx4cEGhdd0OiM60fq7FkykyBx496Fo-

```pascal
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button2: TButton;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Button3: TButton;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

{procedura de salvare a fisierului cu subiecte extrase}
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo2.Lines.SaveToFile(Edit2.Text);
end;

{procedura de incarcare a fisierelor}
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  {incarc din fisierul cu subiecte a carui nume este dat in edit1}
  Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(Edit1.Text);
  {incarc din fisierul cu subiecte extrase deja, a carui nume este dat in edit2}
  Memo2.Lines.LoadFromFile(Edit2.Text);
  {depun numarul de ordine al subiectului in memo1}
  for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count-1 do
    Memo1.Lines[i] := IntToStr(i+1) + '. ' + Memo1.Lines[i];
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
  i: integer;
  atribuit: boolean;
begin
  Randomize; {pornesc generatorul de numere aleatoare}
  atribuit := true; {indicator al atribuirii anterioare a unui subiect}
  while atribuit = true do
  begin
    {citesc aleator o linie din fisierul cu subiecte}
    s := Memo1.Lines[Random(Memo1.Lines.Count-1)];
    atribuit := false;
    for i := 0 to Memo2.Lines.Count do
      if Pos(s, Memo2.Lines[i]) > 0 then
        atribuit := true;    {subiectul a fost atribuit anterior}
  end;
  {am gasit un subiect neatribuit}
  Edit4.Text := Edit3.Text + ': ' + s;
  Memo2.Lines.Add(Edit4.Text); {il adaug la memo2 impreuna cu numele stud.}
end;

end.
```

Comment: What does your debugging tell you?

Comment: BTW, you should call Randomize once only, at startup. Also, your use of Random is wrong. You can never pick the last item. Pass Count rather than Count-1 when calling Random.

Comment: This is the code I received, I know it doesn't work and I wanted to find out why.

Comment: I think I found a solution for the code.

Comment: If you want to know why code doesn't work, you debug it. This is a skill that is often a little lacking in beginners and I recommend that time spent improving your debugging skills will make a huge difference to your progress.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found a solution.

Now it just gives random lines from list even if they are repeated.

```pascal
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button2: TButton;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Button3: TButton;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

{procedura de salvare a fisierului cu subiecte extrase}
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo2.Lines.SaveToFile(Edit2.Text);
end;

{procedura de incarcare a fisierelor}
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  {incarc din fisierul cu subiecte a carui nume este dat in edit1}
  Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(Edit1.Text);
  {incarc din fisierul cu subiecte extrase deja, a carui nume este dat in edit2}
  Memo2.Lines.LoadFromFile(Edit2.Text);
  {depun numarul de ordine al subiectului in memo1}
  for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count-1 do
    Memo1.Lines[i] := IntToStr(i+1) + '. ' + Memo1.Lines[i];
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
  i: integer;
  atribuit: boolean;
begin
  {pornesc generatorul de numere aleatoare}
  i := Memo1.Lines.Count-1;
  {citesc aleator o linie din fisierul cu subiecte}
  s := Memo1.Lines[Random(i)];

  {am gasit un subiect neatribuit}
  Edit4.Text := Edit3.Text + ': ' + s;
  Memo2.Lines.Add(Edit4.Text); {il adaug la memo2 impreuna cu numele stud.}
end;

end.
```

Comment: This won't ever pick the last line. I told you that in comments to the question.

Comment: if I change i:=Memo1.Lines.Count-1; to i:=Memo1.Lines.Count; it pick the last line too.

Comment: Yes. That's what I told you above.